# ThreadPoolExcutor and invokeAll list order

Tags: java, concurrency, threadpoolexecutor

I'm working on `ThreadPoolExcutor`.
I would like to know if in `invokeAll` method, I can be sure that the output (`Future` objects) order is going to be the same as the input (`Callable` list).

```
List<Future<T>> invokeAll(List<Callable<T>> tasks)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What is guaranteed is that the list of futures returned has the same order that the list's iterator you're giving. Note that this method only returns when all tasks have been completed.

Quoting [`invokeAll(tasks)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll-java.util.Collection-) Javadoc:

> **Returns:**
>       a list of Futures representing the tasks, in the same sequential order as produced by the iterator for the given task list, each of which has completed

Comment: What "each of which has completed" means?

Comment: @Tobia The method `invokeAll` returns only when all tasks have been completed.

Comment: + completed task could have terminated either normally or by throwing an exception. A task might finish due to an exception, so it may not have "succeeded". There is no way on a Future to tell the difference

Comment: There is: just call `future.get()`. You either get the desired result, or can catch the `ExecutionException`.