# Executor Service - InvokeAll: How to Map response?

Tags: java, parallel-processing

I am working on parallel execution of 5 Tasks with Executor service, all the 5 tasks returns back with different object results-set depending upon the task.

I am using executor service for parallel execution of tasks :

```
List<Future<Object>> taskResults = ex.invokeAll(callables);
```

But how do we map the result set back with the task(s) ? It may not return back the response in the same order of callable list?

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem. A `List<Future<T>>` is returned by `invokeAll(...)`, so to get the result of each task you just need to query each `Future<T>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that invokeAll() sends back the response of tasks in sequential order which can be used for mapping response back to task ( callables ).

To quote the Javadoc for [`ExecutorService#invokeAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll-java.util.Collection-):

> Returns:
>
> a list of `Future`s representing the tasks, in the same sequential order as produced by the iterator for the given task list, each of which has completed

Source : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll-java.util.Collection-

Answer : [ThreadPoolExcutor and invokeAll list order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34158081/threadpoolexcutor-and-invokeall-list-order)